# Which sort does Comparator internally uses to compare the values and how does it invokes its compare method?

Tags: java, comparator

I just want to know which sorting technique does Comparator uses to sort the things. And how its `compare()` method is invoked even when we never call this method explicitly. 
For example lets say I have class

```
class Person{
    int age;
    int personId;

    //..getters and setters goes here
}
```

And I have another class SortPerson

```
class SortPerson implements Comparator<Person>{
     public int compare(){
        //sorting logic goes here 
        //Assume that I am sorting according to person age. 
     }      
}
```

In my Main class I'm using PriorityQueue

```
class Main{
   public void main(...){
     Queue<Person> q = new PriorityQueue<Person>(5, new SortPerson());
     //q.add() and q.poll() operations goes here
   }
 }
```

So how exactly the Comparator is invoked while performing add and poll operations to maintain a proper sort order?
Thanks.

Comment: source code will answer this question better.

Comment: `Comparator` doesn't use any sorting technique.  It's `PriorityQueue` (etc.) that does the sorting.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Is it? But if I want to sort in reverse order then I generally write this logic in `compare()` method only. So if PriorityQueue does all the sorting why we use Comparator then? Please elaborate, It'll be helpful indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `compare` method doesn't really sort things. Well, technically it does the degenerate case of sorting two objects, but in computer science to avoid confusion, we generally just call that a comparison, not a sort.

Since this is your class, it is your responsibility to implement the `compare` method, using whichever comparison logic you think is appropriate. However, this comparison logic, in order to be sensible, must follow the constraints in the Javadoc for that method in the `Comparator` interface.

The collection class that you are using (in this case, `PriorityQueue`) will call the `compare` method on as many pairs of objects as are necessary to insert the object in its correct place in the collection. However, do not make any assumptions about which objects will be compared; your `compare` method should work correctly for **any** pair of objects - even a pair consisting of an object and itself.

Comment: So does it invokes `compare()` method everytime the add/poll action(in the case of PriorityQueue) happens ? I mean does it creates new instance of Comparator class(SortPerson in this case) at each event?

Comment: Yes, it invokes `compare` in `add` - in fact often it will call it multiple times as it walks along itself trying to find the right place to insert. But no, it doesn't create create new instances - it can't and it doesn't need to. As for `poll`, I don't think that needs a comparison, because the queue is already sorted. Maybe you haven't quite understood the fact that the queue is always maintained in a sorted order.

Comment: Well Thanks a lot @Robin Green for your nice explanation.